# Client Side Yes/No confirmation message before inserting

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sql, webforms

I have an application that adds a form to the database (ASP.NET 2.0)

The button emits `SqlDataSource_3_Inserting` & `SqlDataSource_3_Inserted`.

I must find a way to look if the field X in the database is over the average. This method is called `IsCorrectAmmounts()` and returns a bool.

If bool is true, THEN the user must confirm that the ammount is OK. If it is (e.q. Yes), then the datas are inserted in the database, and the admin must be notified (STMP Email) that the user has add a value over average (method has already been made, `NotifyAdmin()`)

With ALL that said:

How to make a confirmation box AFTER the `IsCorrectAmmounts` gets executed and how to make the yes response submit (e.q. Inserting) the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"AFTER the IsCorrectAmmounts gets executed" add the following code:

```
if (confirm('hey user, is this amount ok?')) {
    yourForm.submit();
}
```

Comment: 1- I would like my C# method (IsCorrectAmounts) to be executed before getting to that confirmation. I must know first if the amounts are over the average. 2- Submit and instert

Comment: Ok, time for a server/client lesson :-)  C# code runs on the server.  Form submissions (and any Javascript code to prompt the user before-hand) runs on the client-side (and then they submit data to the server-side).  Therefore, it is 100% impossible for you to run C# code before making a submission to the server, because you have to make a server submission in order to run the C# code.

Comment: Now, if you wanted what you could do is make an AJAX call to the server before submitting your main form.  This would allow the server to run whatever C# code you wanted, spit back the results, and then your client-side code could react appropriately.

Comment: I know about server side and client side, I just wish there was a way to make the confirm in my c# method (like a winForm), but has you said, it's impossible. I was thinking the same and i'm feeling better not being alone thinking it is not possible. I'll try ajax. What's the method signature for the method called by Ajax? In another project, I did with MVC a JsonResult return type that returns a Json object. How to do that with ASP 2.0? Thanks

Comment: Not an ASP person so I can't really help with that, sorry.  I would suggest making a new post, but I *strongly* suspect that it's a question which has already been answered, so I'd just search for an existing questions first instead.  On the client-side (assuming you're using jQuery) you'll want to look in to the jQuery `$.ajax` method (or its short-hand versions, `$.get` and `$.post`).  Good luck.

Comment: Thank you i'll try looking at what I can do

Answer (score 0):

I created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zw4Gp/3/) for you that demonstrates what you want!

The HTML...

```
<form id='confirmationForm' action='/your/url' method='post'>
    <input id='confirmation' name="confirmation" type="hidden" value="" />
</form>​
```

JavaScript code...

```
function IsCorrectAmmounts() {
    return true;
}

if (IsCorrectAmmounts()) {
   var result = confirm('Is the amount correct')
     , form = document.getElementById('confirmationForm')
     , input = document.getElementById('confirmation');

    if (result) {
        input.value = result;
        form.submit();
    }
}​
```

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zw4Gp/5/) with an AJAX version of the same code using jQuery.

```
function IsCorrectAmmounts() {
    return true;
}

if (IsCorrectAmmounts()) {
   var result = confirm('Is the amount correct');

   if (result) {
       $.post('/your/url', { "result": result }, function () {           
           alert('submitted');
       });
    }
}​
```

Comment: No that's not what I meant. I need to javascript => C# Method => returns string or bool => if string (or bool) returns "confirm", then I must do a confirmation that the user uses over the average fluid. If he answers yes, I must stmp the admin and insert the data into the database.